# Advance deferred looping in while function

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

Expanding on this question in SO [Deferred in $.when while looping an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865869/deferred-in-when-while-looping-an-array)

I have this control structure:-

```
function oldSync(array) { 
  var output = []; // to store the output
  $.each( array, function(key,value) { // runs sequentially
    var item1 = SyncFunction_A(input);
    var item2 = SyncFunction_B(input); 
    output.push({'a': item1, 'b': item2});
  });
  return doSomething(output); // process all output
}
```

Next, I replaced SyncFunction() with AsyncFunction(),

**Question**: How do I convert it to a deferred or async function?

```
function newAync(array) { //
  var output = [];
  $.each( array, function(key,value) { // runs sequentially
    var item1 = AsyncFunction_A(input);
    var item2 = AsncFunction_B(input); 
    item1.then(item2).then(function(data) {
        output.push({'a': data[0], 'b': data[1] });
    }
  });
  return doSomething(output); // FAIL, it doesn't wait for Async
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In real i prefer to check code in sandbox. But i hope you'll catch the main idea

```
function newAync(array) { //
  var output = [],
    promises = [];
  $.each( array, function(key,value) { // runs sequentially
    var item1 = AsyncFunction_A(input);
    var item2 = AsncFunction_B(input); 
    var promise = item1.then(item2).then(function(data) {
        output.push({'a': data[0], 'b': data[1] });
    };

    promises.push(promise);
  });

  var defer = $.Deferred();

  $.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
    defer.resolve(doSomething(output));
  });

  return defer.promise();
}
```

Comment: The main idea is correct. Note: returning a defer.promise() means the promise goes up the food chain. eg: `main()` -> `subroutine()` -> `newAsync()`, hence `main()` requires a `.then()` or `.done()`

Comment: Yep, i return promise to get ability subscribe on  result getted

Comment: It is chaining up to the `main()` routine which gets complex since `newAsync()` may be 4 or more levels deep. Easier to rewrite the logic in `main()` to call `newAsync()` directly and avoid passing the promise up the food chain.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is take advantage of callback functions in order to use the sync functions. I have no idea what your A and B functions are, what they are suppose to do, or what those values represent that you are storing in the `output` array.

Here is an example where you pass an array of urls into a function and it executes a callback when you have gotten the results for each url:

```
function func(urls_array, callback){ // The "callback" will be called when all results have returned.
  var results = []; // Array to store the results of each $.get
  for(var i=0;i<urls_array.length;i++){ // Loop through each url
    $.get(urls_array[i], function(x){ // get the data at the url
      results.push(x); // store the results of this get function
      if(results.length == urls_array.length){ // If all urls have returned
        callback(results); // execute the callback function letting it know that you have finished
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Maybe this will help you understand how sync functions (functions with callbacks) work.

If you want to get a little more specific with your question than we can provide answers that might help, but what you asked is too generic and too may things, such as `SyncFunction_A` are not defined for us.

Comment: With callbacks, I'd adopt libraries like async.js to simplify the coding above (ie: avoid callback-from-hell). Answer is correct though.